# MS Word: change font size of a particular font

Tags: microsoft-word

In a Microsoft Word, if I would like to set the font size to 8 for all text in font Courier New, how should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Find and Replace` (**[Ctrl+H](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/search-and-replace-specific-formatting-fonts-stylesetc-in-microsoft-word/)**)

Click the “More” button on the lower left-hand side to show a lot more options.

Set font `Courier New` to **Find what** and `Courier New, 8pt` to **Replace with**

[image: From https://www.howtogeek.com/]

To avoid the issue altogether you could use [Styles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-or-create-new-styles-d38d6e47-f6fc-48eb-a607-1eb120dec563) that allow you to centrally manage text formatting.